# <ask> file not found after Laravel application Migrate to new server

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to migrate my laravel application to a new server.

Previously my app was running in /var/www/html/demo, and in the new server I put it in /var/www/html as root folder.

Everything works well, but when I try to run some function I get the following error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
natagen.js:519 1

http://mydomaincom/api/publishers/7 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

In the file `natagen.js` i have the following code:

```
var apiPath = function(resource_identifier){
            var baseUrl = $('.base-url').val();
            var baseApi = baseUrl + '/api/';

            return baseApi + resource_identifier;
    };

    /**
     * adPath
     * 
     * @return void
     **/
    var adPath = function(id){
            return apiPath('../app-data/ads/'+id+'/');
    };
```

Also, I cannot access `http://mydomaincom/api/`

Before I migrated to the new server, the file `natagen.js` had the following code:

```
var apiPath = function(resource_identifier){
        var baseUrl = $('.base-url').val();
        var baseApi = baseUrl + '/api/';

        return baseApi + resource_identifier;
    };

    /**
     * adPath
     * 
     * @return void
     **/
    var adPath = function(id){
        return apiPath('../public/app-data/ads/'+id+'/');
    };
```

What path shoud I change in the laravel configuration if I change the url/path directory ?

Comment: could you please try with composer dump-autoload command  and also check if any htaccess related changes.

Comment: Still have same error  `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://139.59.244.170/api/publishers/7 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`